# "Constructed-language" and "conlangs" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

For some reason we have both [constructed-language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructed-language) and [conlangs](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlangs). Could they be either made synonyms or merged?

Comment: stupid question: when is it acceptable to post a conlang here rather than on conlang.se ?

Comment: @NofP when you need help constructing the conlang, it's for [conlang.se]. When you need to figure out how to fit it into what you're writing, that's here. :)

Comment: Now  that you said it, it looks obvious. Silly me! Thank you.

Comment: It's obvious to say, not so obvious to do.

Comment: @NofP As a good rule of thumb, ask on the site that the experts in what you want to know are likely to frequent. If you need help with constructing the language, then [conlang.se] is the place; if you need help with using it in your writing, then you should probably go for [writing.se]. If you need help with figuring out some real-world physics for your hard sci-fi story, then [physics.se] may be appropriate; if you're trying to incorporate it into your soft sci-fi world, [worldbuilding.se] may be the better place; again, for help with getting your story point across, [writing.se]. And so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done -- merged (affecting two questions) and created a synonym.

The tag wiki for [constructed-language](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constructed-language) already contained everything covered in that for [conlangs](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlangs), so merging was straightforward.